Unity Textmesh Pro is blurry/pixelated
I am new to Unity and I'm having trouble with the text in my project. The text appears very pixelated, and I can't figure out why.
Here is an example of how it looks:

I started a new 2D project, installed TextMesh Pro (via the popup), and added a TextMesh Pro text element. However, the text looks blurry and pixelated. In the tutorials I've watched, they just add the text and it looks clear, as it should.
Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how to fix it?

Hard to tell.  But the most note worth thing is you are viewing it at 260% size of normal..

Yes, I know, but everywhere I look, it's sharp even when fully zoomed in. It does look blurry from a distance of 1 and 1.3 too.
Also i litterly didn't do anything yet I just added an image sprite and the text.

You're looking in the game view, which will show the final output of the game at a fixed resolution. Did you mean to zoom in on the scene view instead?

Oh yes in scene view they are prefect. Just to add it press 'F' on the keyboard while some element is focused to jumpt to it, confused me for a bit. Thank you very much.
